# Ruby on Rails - Security Notifications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm working on a project with ROR framework and the gem "Devise" for the authentication.

Actually i have 3 model of users :

- User
- Admin
- Company

I would like to know if there is a way to get the user's account activities with the time and ip (i got it with devise):

When the user login, logout, fail login, change password, unlock account etc ...

Shall i build a new model : security_notifications which is associated with User model, and override devise Controllers to create the notification after every actions ? Or there is a better method ?

Thanks,

Comment: I would suggest forking the gem and calling your notification methods from all cases you wish to notify user..

Comment: Yes, I would do what you said. Override the devise controllers and add your custom behaviour.

Comment: Forking such a massive gem is a bit of an overkill IMO

Comment: Thanks, i think im gonna stay for now on build another model and override devise methods.

Comment: You can look into this gem, https://github.com/ankane/ahoy. It has endless options for visitor tracking.